# Read() function erases text in file

Tags: python

I am a beginning python user and have come upon a dilemma. My program is supposed to read and write in a specific file. While the write function works, the read function simply erases all text from the file.

```
def main():
r = open('C:\\Users\\AM\\Desktop\\cool.txt', 'r')
w = open('C:\\Users\\AM\\Desktop\\cool.txt', 'w')
answer = input('Would you like to read or write? (To leave say "quit")')
if(answer == 'read'):
    if(r.mode == 'r'):
        contents = r.read()
        print(contents)
elif(answer == 'write'):
    w.write(input('What would you like to write?'))
    w.close()
elif(answer == 'quit'):
    quit()
else:
    print('Sorry, I do not understand')
main()
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I would recommend not opening the file till they ask to read or write, just for the sake of not having both open at the same times

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Whitespace is essential in Python.

Comment: Well... don't open your file in write mode, then?

Comment: It's not `read` fault. It's that line `w = open('C:\\Users\\AM\\Desktop\\cool.txt', 'w')` Opening a file in write mode clears it. You need to specify that you want to append to it when openning

Comment: It's really not a good idea to open more than one file handle at a time on a file, things can get messy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. litelite is right. I appreciate the help.